# PostgreSQL Single Mode Command

Tags: postgresql, data-synchronization

I've been working for a while with PostgreSQL and I managed to find out a way to use pg_rewind function in order to resynchronize an old master after a new promoted master (old standby). (using repmgr for HA clustering);

Currently I use a command similar with:

```
postgres –single -D -c archive_mode=on -c archive_command=false
```

in order to access singleusermode.

The next step is to make a checkpoint entering in opened terminal given by previous command: "checkpoint".

My question is the following. How do I pass "checkpoint" as I don't know "command" maybe in order to implement a script to do this automatically.